# Collapse component (bootstrap) not showing because a button is over it

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am building a responsive calendar that has full-width buttons on it (events), and it shows extra info with the collapse component under it. But the button keeps appearing superimposed so it doesn't display the info correctly...

This is one of my event buttons:

```
<!--Event 1-->             
    <div class="div-event col-md-6">
      <span class="date-event col-xs-2 col-md-1"><span class="num-date-event">22</span><br>SEP</span>

      <button class="btn btn-event btn-block col-xs-8 col-md-4" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-1">Kate's Super Party<br>at her house</button>

      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-gift icon-event col-xs-2 col-md-1" aria-hidden="true"><span class="text-event"><br>PARTY</span></span>

      <div class="collapse" id="collapse-1"> 
        <div class="well">
        Hi, I'm a collapsable well that shows something but I can't be seen         because of the weird css I have!
        </div>
        </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
```

I have tried using margin-top and position but it hasn't worked.
Is there a way to "separate" the collapse from the parent row? Or any other way to do it?

Here is the full calendar: https://jsfiddle.net/mrndrmrj/16/

Comment: I think, You need to add `<div class="clearfix"></div>` inside `<div class="well">` check this - https://jsfiddle.net/mrndrmrj/17/

Comment: It doesn´t work, neither if I add some margin to it...

Comment: What I want to do is to show the well -under- the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found that the problem was grouping the event with the collapsable "well", so putting the well outside the div-event made it work!

This is one of the events corrected:

```
<!--Event 1-->  
<div class="div-event">
  <span class="date-event col-xs-2 col-md-2"><span class="num-date-event">22</span><br>SEP</span>

  <button class="btn btn-event btn-block col-xs-8 col-md-8" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-1">Kate's Super Party<br>at her house</button>

  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-gift icon-event col-xs-2 col-md-2" aria-hidden="true"><span class="text-event"><br>PARTY</span></span>

      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>        

      <div class="collapse" id="collapse-1"> 
        <div class="well">
        Hi, I'm a collapsable well that shows something and now I can             be seen, but not the last two guys.
        </div>
      </div>
```

And this is the updated fiddle with the first two events corrected and the last two wrong so you can see the difference...

https://jsfiddle.net/mrndrmrj/20/

Answer (score 0):

In following span add margin-bottom:10px

```
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-gift icon-event col-xs-2 col-md-1" aria-hidden="true"><span class="text-event"><br>PARTY</span></span>
```